# EditText in Relativelayout for Gallery not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, gallery, android-relativelayout

In my app, I have used a relative layout with an imageview and edittext and set each of these layouts in a gallery. When I edit in the edittext it works but when i tries to delete, it is not deleting.

Instead of wrapping the edittext and imageview in a relative layout, if I use them separately in the gallery, then everything works fine.

Can anybody please say why it is not working in case of wrapped inside a relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer, I just need to override a dispatch key event method in my custom gallery.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    boolean handled = false;

    if (getFocusedChild() != null)
    {
        handled = getFocusedChild().dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    if (!handled)
    {
        handled = event.dispatch(this, null, null);
    }

    return handled;
}
```